# october cms gallery - images rotated /upside down

Tags: image-uploading, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm using the [simple-awesome-gallery](https://github.com/sanPuerquitoProgramador/simple-awesome-gallery) plugin so I can easily integrate a gallery in a rainlab blog post. But some images are rotated / upside down after the upload... but in the upload folder they are displayed correctly..

Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks a lot! 
Br,
Karlien
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It often happens that images do not have the correct orientation data written in their data, especially when they were shot with a mobile phone.

It helps to open these images with an image viewer like IrfanView, XnView (Windows) or Preview (on a Mac), rotate the image left, then back right and save it again. This way the orientation data gets written correctly.